# Frog bloated with pool water

Tags: hyperplasia

I found a gray tree frog in pool skimmer basket, he seems quite alive but terribly bloated with water. I tried holding it upside down a bit to see if some water would come out but only a few drops. Any ideas if there's anything I can do, or just let nature take it's course maybe he'll survive if given enough time without predators (cats and birds and whatever, around here in Ottawa Ontario).

Comment: I have no expertise in this, but it could be the pool chemicals were absorbed and caused this, and if so allowing it access to a large amount of fresh (nonpool) water might give it the best chance to survive.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is trivial. This site is for academics, researchers and students of biology. It is not an animal rescue society.

Comment: I can't say if the question is trivial but there can be multiple possibilities for why the frog is bloated. Unless you provide some additional details providing a conclusive answer would be difficult. However, it seems that the frog is affected by chlorine in water. Nonetheless, we consider personal medical questions and health advice for both humans and animals, as off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Most frogs die in minutes in chlorinated swimming pool water , after some time they will swell with gas. I have pulled toads out of pools and they have survived ; I assume their dry skin is less permeable to pool chemicals than frogs.

Comment: The pool is salt based, i.e. you don't usually smell chlorine after swimming. And the only chemicals in it were a bit of shock a couple weeks ago to kill the algae, and based on the water sample yesterday, that's pretty much dissipated so maybe its not so bad.